# Get output of cell range operations into one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Columns A and B show distance ranges (from 0 to 29km, 30 to 59km and so on) and column C shows a corresponding fee (amount of currency), like this:

```
 1. | A  | B   | C   | 
 2. | 0  | 29  | 400 |
 3. | 30 | 59  | 500 | 
 4. | 60 | 89  | 700 |
 5. | 90 | 119 | 900 |
```

and so on up to 2000 or so.

I need to input a value - a distance within the range of `columns A and B` - in one given cell (ultimately on another worksheet), and get the matching result - the fee in another, single cell (ultimately on another worksheet).

I got the general formula to work, but only to the extent where it displays my match in the corresponding row, showing the values in the non-matched rows as "0", according to a formula in an `E column`: `=IF(AND($D$3>=$A3;$D$3<=$B3);$C3;0)`

Where `cell D3` is a user distance input cell for extracting the fee to the formula cell).

To recap, I get a column of "0"'s and one match corresponding to my ABC range value, but instead, I just need a single cell with the match, located at my choosing.

Answer (score 2):

Using your references use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($D$3,;$A:$C;3;TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use **MATCH** function with **match_type** equal to **1** (*"less than"* match) to find the row number and then use **INDEX** function to fetch the fee from the corresponding row number in the fee range.

Let's suppose your lookup value is in cell B7. Use formula:

```
=INDEX(C2:C5;MATCH(B7;A2:A5;1))
```

In this example

- MATCH in the second argument of INDEX returns the number of the first row in A2:A5 range for which the cell value is *less* than B7 and
- INDEX fetches the value with this number from the range C2:C5, specified in the first argument.

In fact you don't need column B (provided that it only specifies the upper boundary for your distance, which shall be equal to the lower boundary of the next distance bin anyway).

Please, consult documentation on INDEX and MATCH functions and examine *Lookup & Reference* group in the *Function Library* in *Formulas* tab for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, trying to guess the amount using trendline formula.

Take *B* and *C* column, and add scatterplot, then right click on one of the points on the plot, and click `Add Trendline...`. Try out different trendline setting and check the *R2* value, closer to 1 the better.

See below example, with just 4 points it is not easy to find a good trendline formula, but still it gives *R2=0.9968* for Polynomial trendline. You can see the formula for the trendline, copy paste it to *B10* and adapt, in this example it is:

```
=0.0267*B9^2 + 3.2965*B9 + 391.67
```

The value 718 is close enough to expected value of 700. As you said, "it goes up to 2000", with that many points we will get a better fitting formula to guess the amount better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's quite interesting. It might be overkill for my needs right now, but I might use it later on!

Comment: @mha_sopot [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)